# Sigsegv on gsoap copy

Tags: c++, qt, wsdl, gsoap

I'm tryning to build a service con gsoap. The code is:

```
ArchivatorCoreService server;
ArchivatorCoreService *tserver;
int port = 8080;
SOAP_SOCKET m, s;
m = server.bind(NULL, port, 100);
if (!soap_valid_socket(m))
{
      exit(1);
}
else
{
  qDebug() << "Info: Bind: Succesfully socket connection: " << m << ". Port " << port 
}
for (;;)
{
  qDebug() << "waiting...";
  s = server.accept();

  if (!soap_valid_socket(s))
  {
    if (server.errnum)
    {
       qDebug() << "1"; << "Error: Failed accept: " << messagec;
       exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    qDebug() << "Info: Thread " << i << " accepts socket " << s << " connection from   IP " << ((server.ip >> 24)&0xFF) << "." << ((server.ip >> 16)&0xFF) << "." << ((server.ip >> 8)&0xFF) << "." << ((server.ip)&0xFF);

}
qDebug() << "2";
tserver = server.copy(); // make a safe copy
qDebug() << "3";
```

In line tserver = server.copy(); error sigsegv.

ArchivatorCoreService heracly of soap;

Thanks you very much

Comment: Your "server" variable never has been initialized, just declared. It contains random garbage.

Comment: In c++ ArchivatorCoreService server; call default constructor, ¿no?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of gsoap you are using; however versions prior to 2.8.5 have an issue with memory leaks and SIGSEGVs with the C++ code that is generated. See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150380/gsoap-multithreading/8245349#8245349) for a few more details.