# gSOAP C++ Multithreaded standalone server and client example

Tags: c++, soap, gsoap

I am new to gSOAP, can some body post a working gSOAP multithreaded c++ standalone server and client. in the gSOAP document , multithreaded stand alone server does not have details on where to call the webservice functions , like int ns_add(int a , int b) , there is no call to the functions defined in the header file calc.h in the main server class - calc.cpp.

Please give step by step instruction, which will help new comers like me.

your reply would be appreciated.

Comment: See this link for a C++ multi-threaded server example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150380/gsoap-multithreading/8245349#8245349.  If you want better answers then you need to do some work yourself, what code have you tried? Why not start creating such instructions yourself?

Comment: Hi , I tried the link you have sent, but it is not mentioned how the ns_add, ns__mul are served from void *process_request(void *calc). that is why posted this question. creating an example myself is also a good option , I will try that

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of gsoap in c++ :
in the header file we have for example this functions(services):

```
int yb__add_list(char *name, char *tel, char **result);
int yb__del_list(int no, char **result); 
int yb__get_tel_by_name(char *name, char **result);
int yb__get_name_by_tel(char *tel, char **result);
int yb__get_list(char **result);
```

After generating our stubs by running soapcpp2  interface.h
we have some files, check documentation to know about it: soapStub.h, soapH.h, soapC.c, soapClient.c, soapServer.c
Then we can implement service like that:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ int m, s; /* master and slave sockets */
struct soap soap;

soap_init(&soap);
load_list();
show_list();
if (argc < 2)
soap_serve(&soap);  /* serve as CGI application */
else
{ m = soap_bind(&soap, NULL, atoi(argv[1]), 100);
if (m < 0)
{ soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
  exit(-1);
}
fprintf(stderr, "Socket connection successful: master socket = %d\n", m);
for ( ; ; )
{ s = soap_accept(&soap);
  fprintf(stderr, "Socket connection successful: slave socket = %d\n", s);
  if (s < 0)
  { soap_print_fault(&soap, stderr);
    exit(1);
  } 
  soap_serve(&soap);
  soap_end(&soap);
  }
  }
  return 0;
  } 

 int yb__add_list(struct soap *soap, char *name, char *tel, char **result)
 {
 printf("the name is %s, tel is %s\n", name, tel);
 *result = (char *) soap_malloc(soap, 50);
 if(add_list(name, tel) > 0)
 strcpy(*result, "Success!");
 else
 strcpy(*result, "Failed!");
 show_list();
 save_list();
 return SOAP_OK;
 }
 int yb__del_list(struct soap *soap, int no, char **result)
 {
 *result = (char *) soap_malloc(soap, 50);
 if(delete_list(no) > 0)
 strcpy(*result, "Success!");
 else
 strcpy(*result, "Failed!");
 save_list();
 return SOAP_OK;
 }
 int yb__get_tel_by_name(struct soap *soap, char *name, char **result)
 {
 char tel[50];
 *result = (char *) soap_malloc(soap, 200);
 if(get_tel_by_name(name, tel ) == 1)
 sprintf(*result, "The tel of %s is: \n%s\nSuccess!", name, tel);
 else
 strcpy(*result, "Failed!");
 return SOAP_OK;
 }
 int yb__get_name_by_tel(struct soap *soap, char *tel, char **result)
 {
 char name[50];

 *result = (char *) soap_malloc(soap, 200);
 if(get_name_by_tel(tel, name) == 1)
 sprintf(*result, "The owner of %s is: \n%s\nSuccess!", tel, name);
 else
 strcpy(*result, "Failed!");
 return SOAP_OK;
 }
 int yb__get_list(struct soap *soap, char **result)
 {
 *result = (char *)malloc(1024);
 get_list(*result);
 return SOAP_OK;  
 }
```

You can execute so your service as a sand alone server in a terminal ./server +Port
Then in client side :

```
const char server[] = "localhost:8080/";
int executecmd(char *inbuf,  struct soap *p_soap);
int main(void)
{
struct soap soap;
char inbuf[MAX_CANON];
int ret;
soap_init(&soap);
for( ; ; ) {
fputs(NEWLINE_STRING, stdout);
fputs(CLIENT_PROMPT_STRING, stdout);
if (fgets(inbuf, MAX_CANON, stdin) == NULL)
  break;
if (*(inbuf + strlen(inbuf) - 1) == NEWLINE_SYMBOL)
  *(inbuf + strlen(inbuf) - 1) = 0;
if(is_blank_line(inbuf))
  continue;
if((ret = executecmd(inbuf, &soap)) < 0) 
  break; /* accept the quit command */
else if(ret == 0)
  continue; /* encount the error command */

}
return 1;
}

int executecmd(char *inbuf,  struct soap *p_soap)
{
char *result;
int n;
char **chargv;

if((n = makeargv(inbuf, BLANK_STRING, &chargv)) < 0){
printf("makeargv error\n");
exit(0);
}
if(!strcmp(chargv[0], "add") && n == 3){
soap_call_yb__add_list(p_soap, server, "", chargv[1], chargv[2], &result);
printf("%s\n", result);
return 0;
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], "del") && n == 2 ){
soap_call_yb__del_list(p_soap, server, "", atoi(chargv[1]), &result);
printf("%s\n", result);
return 0;
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], "gettel") &&  n == 2){
soap_call_yb__get_tel_by_name(p_soap, server, "", chargv[1], &result);
printf("%s\n", result);
return 0;
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], "getname") &&  n == 2){
soap_call_yb__get_name_by_tel(p_soap, server, "", chargv[1], &result);
printf("%s\n", result);
return 0;
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], "list")){
soap_call_yb__get_list(p_soap, server, "", &result);
printf("%s\n", result);
return 0;   
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], QUIT_STRING)){
return -1;
}
else if(!strcmp(chargv[0], HELP_STRING)){
printf("The usage of the command:\n");
printf("\"add name tel\"     add new entry to address book.\n");
printf("\"del no\"           delete entry by its corresponding phone number.\n");
printf("\"getname tel\"      get name by the corresponding phone number.\n");
printf("\"gettel name\"      get phone number by name.\n");
printf("\"list\"             list the current entries in the address book.\n");
printf("\"help\"             get help.\n");
printf("\"quit\"             quit this client.\n");
return 0;    
}
else{
printf("Can not execute this command.\n input \"help\" to get usage of commands.");
return 0;
}
return 1;
}
```

You can run client also in terminal like that : ./client

Answer (score 1):

You can find many examples of gsoap where you have installed gsoap on your system. You will find a **SAMPLE** folder inside the installation folder to help you understand different applications of gSoap.