# Gsoap 2.8.17 undefined reference to 'soap_initialize'

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference, undefined, gsoap

I'm new with gsoap and trying to build a multithreading server standalone, reading the problems with the ubuntu package with memory by default, I installed the last version 2.8.17. Reading some posts here I tried the example posted by jackson

[gSOAP Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150380/gsoap-multithreading)

so ... I execute soapcpp2 -i -S calc.h

and then when I compile this, I get this message :

In function `CalculatorService::reset()':
soapCalculatorService.cpp:(.text+0x24f): undefined reference to`soap_initialize'

I've been looking where this method is declared but no look, hope you can give me some ideas! . Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to link with -lgsoap++ that define soap_init (or soap_initialiaze) depending on the gSOAP version.

The command to compile and link command could be something like :

```
g++ calc.cpp soapCalculatorService.cpp soapC.cpp -l gsoap++
```